# How to divide the contents of a file depending on a particular time slot

Tags: c#, .net

I want to log certain data . But I want to partition it into certain time slots ( for eg data collected over a period of 20 s is stored as one section and then maybe I could add a marker that represents the end of that particular timeslot ( maybe an asterik "*")). How do I do it?

There does exist a "timer" tool in C# .net. but am not really sure how to go abt doing it..

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just log the timestamp for each entry (e.g. via `DateTime.UtcNow`)? Then it can be partitioned later by whatever's reading the file (LINQ would make this really easy).

I don't think that baking the partitioning into the log file itself is a good idea - it makes it impossible to change your partitioning scheme later, and makes the logging code itself more complex. Post-processing more "raw" data is more flexible and probably simpler.

Comment: Writing the data in CSV format would also be a good idea with the time stamp as one of the columns. Later one can use Excel to do sorting, searching and basic analysis of the data.

Comment: okey will try doing that. bt is dere a way to do what i have earlier proposed...??

Comment: @olive: You'd need to keep track of when the last timeslot started, and when you log an entry, check to see if you're still in it - if not, write a * before the log entry, and work out the new timeslot start time.